# Why Ruby on Rails books or references always say Update is by PUT and Destroy is by DELETE when it is not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

Because if I use Fiddler to monitor it, it is:

```
CRUD       Method  Path        With              Idempotent?   action
----       ------  ----        ----              -----------   ------
Create     POST    /foos/                        No            create
Retrieve   GET     /foos/:id                     Yes           show
Update     POST    /foos/:id   _method=put       Yes           update
Destroy    POST    /foos/:id   _method=delete    Yes           destroy
```

so `PUT` and `DELETE` (as HTTP verb) are not actually used.  But why do Rails books and references always say it is `PUT` and `DELETE`?

Answer (score 4):

Because web *browsers* have no interface to generate `PUT` or `DELETE` requests.

Of course, clients that you program have enough flexibility to use `PUT` and `DELETE` as intended, but browsers can really only use `GET` and `POST`.

Comment: ??? all a browser has to do is send in TCP/IP a `PUT` or `DELETE` instead of the ASCII characters `POST`

Comment: @動靜能量, yes, from a programmer's point of view it is trivial to do. But, as far as I know, _none_ of the Big Browsers have any interface to expose this to humans, and the HTML specification doesn't allow specifying the correct HTTP verb to use when making requests. (Which would allow the human driving the browser to remain blissfully in the dark. :)

Comment: interesting... your answer is none of the browser supports it... and Will's answer is none of the server supports it.  But you get 2 votes...

Comment: Browsers are the issue.  Client programs do send PUT and DELETE.

Comment: @John browsers are client programs too... you mean browsers are the issue -- other client programs do send PUT and DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

Because they SHOULD be PUT and DELETE but many servers out of the box do not support PUT and DELETE, so they tunnel it through POST.