# rails 4 - update attribute with browser's back button only when leaving a webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser-cache, back-button, update-attributes

I am trying to track which page user visit and when user access and leave. I store access time successfully by following the advise in [how to change database values with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775249/rails-how-to-change-database-values-with-a-link). Here is the flow:

- (in viewA) user click the button in pageA
- (in actionB) create a new record to store access time
- (in actionB) redirect to pageB

But when I want to apply this method to store leave time, I got some problems. I want to **update the time when user leave the page** to the record I just create. The above method just work while user click the "back" button which I create in webpage.

If user click browser's back button, it will do nothing. I guess the reason why `update_attribute` doesn't work is that ruby on rails do not call the action in controller while browser's back button been clicked......
**How can it work while user click browser's back button?**

The flow might be something like this:

- (in viewB) user click the "back" button in pageB OR click browser's back button
- (in actionA) update leave time
- (in actionA) redirect to pageA

> review.html.erb

```
# while click the "Back" button, redirect to "store" and update leave time for the record just create
<%= button_to "Back", {:action=>"stores", :user=>@product.user, :order=>@product.order}, :method=>:get %>
```

> controller.rb

```
def store
    @user = params[:user]
    @order = params[:order]
    @lastevent = Event.where(:user=>@user).order("id").last
    @lastevent.update_attributes!(:leave_time => Time.now)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to solve it:

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    <% update_method_helper %>
  }      
});
```

use it as a partial and call this partial in every page you want to use it(if you want all pages use it in the layout).

Comment: I put this script in the page I redirect to, but it seems nothing happened. What is "update_method_helper"? I got undefined local variable or method, so I change to what I want it to do in the action, is that correct? (I put this two line instead: `@lastevent = Event.where(:user=>@user).order("id").last @lastevent.update_attributes!(:leave_time => Time.now)`

Comment: I also try to put this script in the page which I leave, update_attribute does work, but it works everytime when I open this page instead of when I click back button and **leave** this page......am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems you do everyhing fine

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I want `update_attribute` to work **only when leaving a webpage** (click browser's back button), but this script works directly when I open a webpage...... Is it possible to do what I want via javascript?